# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' in Python. How to preprocess before tokenizing the text content?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

The data set I am using looks like this. It is a video captioning data set with captions under the column 'caption' with multiple captions for a single video clip.

```
video_id       caption
mv89psg6zh4    A bird is bathing in a sink.
mv89psg6zh4    A faucet is running while a bird stands.
mv89psg6zh4    A bird gets washed.
mv89psg6zh4    A parakeet is taking a shower in a sink.
mv89psg6zh4    The bird is taking a bath under the faucet.
mv89psg6zh4    A bird is standing in a sink drinking water.
R2DvpPTfl-E    PLAYING GAME ON LAPTOP.
R2DvpPTfl-E    THE MAN IS WATCHING LAPTOP.
l7x8uIdg2XU    A woman is pouring ingredients into a bowl.
l7x8uIdg2XU    A woman is adding milk to some pasta.
l7x8uIdg2XU    A person adds ingredients to pasta. 
l7x8uIdg2XU    the girls are doing the cooking.
```

It is working on the "CandidateA" json File [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pnhCcLVO7Sx5GtCIrPz7fsn_VQh_Gq9P/view?usp=sharing)
However, it is not working on the "Referencedf" json file which looks like this (the complete file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FElwUxlGvrS26BQoNf0uwMbzH7dJT-On/view?usp=sharing)):

```
(Excerpt only):
[{"video_id":"mv89psg6zh4_33_46","caption":"A bird in a sink keeps getting under the running water from a faucet."},{"video_id":"mv89psg6zh4_33_46","caption":"A bird is bathing in a sink."},{"video_id":"mv89psg6zh4_33_46","caption":"A bird is splashing around under a running faucet."},{"video_id":"60x_yxy7Sfw_1_7","caption":"A MAN IS WATCHING A LAPTOP."},{"video_id":"60x_yxy7Sfw_1_7","caption":"A man is sitting at his computer."}]
```

This is the following code I am applying:

```
import json
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

with open("Referencedf.json", 'r') as f:
    datastore = json.load(f)

captions = []
video_id = []

for item in datastore:
    captions.append(item['caption'])

tokenizer = Tokenizer(oov_token="<OOV>")
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(captions)
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-63fee6e467f1> in <module>
      1 tokenizer = Tokenizer(oov_token="<OOV>")
----> 2 tokenizer.fit_on_texts(captions)
      3 word_index = tokenizer.word_index
      4 print(len(word_index))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\text.py in fit_on_texts(self, texts)
    221                                             self.filters,
    222                                             self.lower,
--> 223                                             self.split)
    224             for w in seq:
    225                 if w in self.word_counts:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\text.py in text_to_word_sequence(text, filters, lower, split)
     41     """
     42     if lower:
---> 43         text = text.lower()
     44 
     45     if sys.version_info < (3,):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Edit:

As suggested by @MahindraSinghMeena, I removed the Null rows from the dataframe beforehand only so as to avoid the error by using

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Comment: The code that you have shared works well with the latest version of TensorFlow that is 2.2.0.rc3 . What is the tensorflow version you are using ?

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KWY5wS60JXEF8z-J-xuuhAw-EQNlLqVU

Comment: @MahendraSinghMeena The issue is with the "Referencedf.json" file I am using. I tried with another short file "CandidateA.json" and then it is working fine. I have editted and attached the two json files for reference. Please check.

Comment: Can't find the "Referencedf.json" file. That error could be due to some empty or null strings in that file for the caption field.

Comment: @MahendraSinghMeena It should be available now. Can you recheck? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if you have some incorrect data in the text being fed to the Tokenizer, as the error message suggests that it found some element to be None. So a cleanup in the data should be done to remove such cases.

You can see in the following snippet, that an entry has invalid text for caption.

```
import json
datastore = json.load(open('/Referencedf.json', 'r'))

for d in datastore:
  if d['caption'] is None:
    print(d)
```

```
{'video_id': 'SKhmFSV-XB0_12_18', 'caption': None}
```